# Yii2 make an input field appear only in create

Tags: forms, yii2

I would like to make an input field appear only in the 'create' form and not in the 'update' form. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by following way

```
if ($model->isNewRecord){
    echo $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => "Enter password"]);
}
```

Comment: PHP tags are not necessary here because this code will be inserted between form declaration (neither at the beginning nor at the end of the file).

Answer (score 0):

You can use $model->isNewRecord in many creative ways that can help you do some stuff depending on create/update.

i.e.
**Hide a field**

```
if ($model->isNewRecord){
    echo $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput()
}
```

**Change a style, class or property like readonly**

```
$isEditable = (model->isNewRecord);
$class = (model->isNewRecord)?'class-a':'class-b';
echo $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput([
         'readonly'=>$isEditable, 
         'disabled' => $isEditable,
         'class'=>$class])
```

**Changing a label**

```
Html::submitButton( ($model->isNewRecord)
  ?'Create'
  :'Update',
  ['class' => 'btn btn-success','id' => 'submit-btn',]);
```

**Show a different button**

```
echo ($model->isNewRecord)   
? Html::a('Cancel', ['index'], ['class' => 'btn btn-warning'])   
: Html::a('Close', ['otherplace'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
```

You can play a lot with `$model->isNewRecord` and actually modify some stuff depending on the state.

And many other stuff.